# Please show suggested edits in the network profile activity page

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, profile-page, network-profile

Often, I suggest an edit to a HNQ question (maybe creating an account just for that). However, I probably wouldn't normally visit the site of that HNQ again, but I would like to know what happens to my suggested edit. That's easy if it got approved, but the more interesting case is if it was rejected. Rejected edits are opportunities for learning, and not being able to track them means I might lose such opportunities.

In the current system, it's difficult to keep track of edits I suggested to various HNQs. The network profile's activity tab only shows approved edits, and even those are lost in the volume of edits I make elsewhere where I have edit privileges.

Please add a "suggestions" subtab like in the per-site profile's all activity tab.